# VBA編集データを上書きしたい

Tags: vba

参照ボタンに検索したい従業員の番号を入力すると、フォームにデータが参照されます。
そこからデータを編集し、編集確定ボタンを押すと表に上書きされるような仕様にしたいです。
しかし、今のコードだと14行のような感じで反映されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**VBA**

参照ボタンを押した際の処理です

```
 '編集確定ボタンを押したとき'
Private Sub OkButton1_Click()

    Dim x As Integer
    With Worksheets("メンバー")
    For x = 2 To 10
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, x).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Text
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Text = ""
    Next
    End With

End Sub

 '参照ボタンを押した時の処理'
Private Sub RefBtn_Click()

    'もし参照する値が入力されていなかったら'
    If Me.IDTextBox = "" Then
        MsgBox "参照する番号を入力してください。"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'データの参照'
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    With Worksheets("メンバー")

    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    r = Application.Match(Val(IDTextBox.Text), rng, 0)

    For i = 2 To 5
        Controls("TextBox" & i).Text = .Cells(r + 1, i)
    Next i
    If .Cells(r + 1, 6) = "男" Then
        Man.Value = True
    Else
        Woman.Value = True
    End If

    ComboBox1.Text = .Cells(r + 1, 7)
    For i = 6 To 8
    Controls("TextBox" & i).Text = .Cells(r + 1, i + 2)
    Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

一応メンバー追加の登録のコードです

```
 '現在作業中のシートを選択'
    ActiveSheet.Select
    If Cells(8, 1).Value = 1 Then 'cell値変更あるかも'

        '入力されている一番最後のセルの番号を取得'
        CellCount = Cells(7, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

        'IDTextBoxの値を"従業員番号"の欄に入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 1).Value = Me.IDTextBox.Value

        '姓を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

        '名を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value

        'セイを入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value

        'メイを入力 '
        Cells(CellCount, 5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

        '選択した性別を入力'
        If Man.Value = True Then
            Cells(CellCount, 6).Value = Me.Man.Caption

        ElseIf Woman.Value = True Then
            Cells(CellCount, 6).Value = Me.Woman.Caption

        End If

        '交通手段を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 7).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value

        '最寄り駅を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 8).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value

        '交通費を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 9).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value

        '時給を入力'
        Cells(CellCount, 10).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

'参照ボタンを押した時の処理'のプログラムは以下のようになっていて、書き込み先のセルの行は、ActiveCell.Row　です。
　質問のスクリーンショットで、G14セルが選択されている(ActiveCellになっている）ようなので、14行目（B14:H14)にデータが書き込まれたのは、そのせいだと思います。（A15セルを選択した状態で、編集確定ボタンをクリックすると１５行目に書き込まれるだろうと思います。

```
Private Sub OkButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    With Worksheets("メンバー")
        For x = 2 To 10
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, x).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Text
            Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Text = ""
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

『編集確定ボタンを押すと表に上書きされるような仕様にしたい』というのであれば、
どの行からデータを取得したのかを覚えておいて、その行にデータを書き戻すようにしてください。
（ActiveCell.Rowを書き戻す行にするのは、まずいです。どこのセルを選択した状態でプログラムを実行するのかが判らないですから）